# What is the asymptotic time complexity of the number of steps of "Half Or Triple Plus One" ( HOTPO)?

Tags: time-complexity, open-problem

The "Half Or Triple Plus One" process goes as follows:

> 1. start with $x=n$ for some value of $n$
> 2. if ($x$ is odd)
>
>    $x = 3x+1$
>
>    else
>
>    $x = \frac{x}{2}$
> 3. if ($x$ > 1) goto (2)

Define $f(n) = $

```
total stopping time of $n$, i.e. The number of steps required for the procedure to halt.
```

---

The [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) suggests that the process stops for every value of $n$, hence if the conjecture holds, $f$ is well defined.

---

The question is:

> **What is the asymptotic time complexity of calculating $f(n)$?**

Comment: How is $f(n) = \Theta(n)$ not obvious?

Comment: I was under the impression that because the number of steps before any given n converges to 1 can vary significantly between successive values of n, it was not as simple as saying its proportional to n. For instance, the sequence for n == 4 is shorter than for n == 3.

Comment: There is no known explicit bound on the complexity of f, and proving one would go a long way towards solving the conjecture.

Comment: Just to make clear, my first comment was for a completely different $f(n)$ (or at least the way I understood it).

Comment: to go further than EJ's point, basically any time complexity bounds on the problem would be _equivalent_ to a proof. at heart the conjecture is about the upper bound time complexity of the computation/ trajectories. in line with this, there seems some possibility that CS or complexity theoretic approaches have not been tried on the problem & might go further than prior analysis which tends to be more number-theoretic or mathematical. it is easy to conjecture various simple function bounds that "seem" sufficient for "most" finite values that can be verified computationally.

Comment: BTW there are results of the type $\Omega(n^c)$ of the numbers in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ have finite stopping time, for $c < 1$ a fixed constant. If that's of interest I can find the citation.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I'd love to see some of these results!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, as the conjecture is still open, we can't say if $f$ is even defined for every $n$.

Let's assume that if $f(n)=\infty$, then the algorithm is required to output $-1$.

In 1972 [Conway showed](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/pdf/392904.pdf?pg1=MR&r=1&s1=392904) that a generalization of the problem of determining whether $f(n)= \infty$ is undecidable. In particular, no algorithm can always determine, on input $n$ and sequences $(a_i)_{i=0}^{p-1}$, $(b_i)_{i=0}^{p-1}$, whether the process that starts with $x = n$ and iteratively maps $x$ to $a_ix + b_i$ whenever $x \equiv i \pmod{p}$ terminates at 1 in finite time. Here the $a_i$  and $b_i$ are assumed to be chosen so that the results are always integers. This result isn't necessarily applicable for the Collatz function, which presents only one fixed choice of $a_i$ and $b_i$ and leaves only $n$ as a variable.

---

Side note: The [A006877](http://oeis.org/A006877) series in http://oeis.org/ contains the values of $n$ for which $\forall m<n:f(m)<f(n)$.

Comment: Does Conway's result imply we cannot provide a complexity measure of f(n)? Could we provide a probabilistic measure for ranges of n?

Comment: If the finiteness of $f(n)$ is undecidable, then $f(n)$ is not bounded by any recursive function. However, Conway's result does not apply to this particular f, but to a more general class of similar functions.

Comment: RB, can you edit your answer to make clear the Conway has *not* shown undecidablity for the Collatz function, but for a related more general class of functions.

Comment: any proof/evidence that the Collatz problem itself has some aspect of undecidability embedded in it would be a theoretical breakthrough...

Answer (score 9):

By request, two facts that are known and seem somewhat related to your question.

- As a lower bound: infinitely many integers $n$ take time $\Omega(\log n)$. [Applegate and Lagarias](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2003-72-242/S0025-5718-02-01425-4/home.html).
- As a sort of an upper bound: $\Omega(N^c)$ positive integers bounded by $N$ reach $1$ in finite time, where $c \approx 0.84$. [Krasikov and Lagarias](http://journals.impan.pl/cgi-bin/doi?aa109-3-4).

Hopefully you have read [Lagarias's survey](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-78-prev.pdf) before asking the question.